# How to upload a in-memory RTSP stream file to google cloud?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to record from the RTSP stream and save locally using the RTSP-recorder. But I want to send the file directly to google cloud. Is there a way we can send the file directly to cloud?

Comment: Have you tried python boto client library or similar translated version for node? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I'm using node RtspRecorder to record and save to local storage. In this, I cannot add the path to cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

If your using linux or MAC OS you could use [Cloud Storage fuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) to mount the GCS bucket as a  filesystem and it will sync the local data with the bucket.